# Titanium] How to add multiple markers without uploading each time the image?

Tags: image, dictionary, upload, titanium

I am working on Titanium Studio, build: 3.0.1 and trying to make an android app.

On this map I add many markers. I find properties of theses markers in my database.

This is how it works :

```
 var i = 1;
while(i<qr.rowCount) //I use i because qr.validRow always return false....
{
    var marker = Ti.Map.createAnnotation({
        latitude: qr.fieldByName('lat'),
        longitude: qr.fieldByName('lng'),
        title: qr.fieldByName('nom')+' '+ qr.fieldByName('prix_hh')+' €',
        subtitle: qr.fieldByName('adresse'),
        pincolor:Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
        animate:true,
        image: 'images\\'+qr.fieldByName('prix_hh')+'_app.png',
        myid: qr.fieldByName('id') // Custom property to uniquely identify this annotation.
    });
    mapView.addAnnotation(marker);
    qr.next();
    i++;
}
```

For each marker I give the path of the icon while saying :

```
image: 'images\\'+qr.fieldByName('prix_hh')+'_app.png'
```

It works perfectly but for each marker Titanium uploads the image and so as I get more than 180 markers it takes a long long time (30 seconds). As you can see I am always using the same icons, so I guess I could store them somewhere and then do not need to upload them again. I tried to do this but I did not success.

```
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:09,921] get images\3_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\3_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:10,062] get images\2_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\2_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:10,177] get images\2_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\2_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:10,226] get images\3_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\3_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:10,358] get images\3_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\3_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:10,404] get images\3_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\4_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:10,519] get images\3_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\3_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:10,779] get images\3_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\3_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:10,864] get images\3_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\3_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:10,966] get images\2_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\2_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:11,053] get images\2_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\2_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:11,148] get images\3_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\3_app.png
[INFO] [2013-03-07 00:39:11,207] get images\2_app.png: C:\Users\Bomp\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\MGB\Resources\android\images\2_app.png
```

Comment: This looks like FastDev which is only activated on Emulator. Did you test this behavior on a device?

Comment: You are right! I installed app on my Nexus S and I donc have this issue anymore... but I don't have my personnalised icons either. I'll try to fix this. Thank you very much!

Comment: maybe your images are not provided in a correct resolution for your device. you also can disable fastdev